# SwiftUI Modal View Overlay

Tags: swift, swiftui, overlay

In SwiftUI is there a way to create an overlay view that has a 'down' state and an 'up' state that can be slid up/down but locks in the up or down position? The view should always be on the screen but either locked in the up or down position

For example this chat view is the inspiration:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you explored '.presentationDetents' modifier.

Comment: @RohitPradhan yes but that is for presentation, which means it has to be presented and can be dismissed which is not what I am looking ofr